# Android: GCM without Google Account?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

We're building an app that relies on Google Cloud Messaging to recieve data. The app will be installed on several tablets, that each should collect different data from our server. When trying the register our test tablet with our GCM server-side, we get the error "Google Play Services out of date. Requires 3265100 but found 3027105".

We have not attached the device to a Google account, since our understanding was that if you are running 4.0.4 or higher you do not need this. We're running 4.2.2 on an Acer Iconia A1. We really don't want to attach an account to each tablet (could possible be hundreds of them).

How do we update Google Play Services, or do we even need it?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GCM from the google play service library yes you need a google account because google play services gets updated through the play store.

you can however not use google play services and just download the GCM library from the SDK Manager but its not going to get updated anymore so if there are any bugs or anything they wont be fixed. all the new updated will go into the Google Play Services

Comment: We think we've got past the Google Play Services problem. Now we're getting "SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE" when running gcm.register(). Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: It can be caused by there not being google play services or an outdated version of it. There is also a a bug report of this issue too https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&q=57699&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&id=57699#makechanges. The official definition of this error is found here http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging.html#ERROR_SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE

Comment: `SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE` is caused for a plethora of reasons: https://eladnava.com/google-cloud-messaging-extremely-unreliable/ Please consider an alternative, drop-in replacement for GCM which does not require Google Play Services, nor does it depend on GCM: Pushy (https://pushy.me/). Full disclosure - I am the Founder & CEO at Pushy.